# GA4 Custom Dimensions flowing into GA, but can't run reports on it

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

To facilitate A/B testing, I pass google analytics a custom dimension that tells GA whether this user has seen the A or the B experience. Then I run reports where I can see how the A users and B users engaged differently with my website. I've been doing this for years with Universal Analytics, but I'm having trouble getting it working in GA4. I think I have everything set up correctly, but when I run a report in GA4, it gives me no data for my custom dimension.

I pass the custom dimension to Google Tag Manager via the data layer. And Google Tag Manager is set up to send the dimension to GA4 on page load. In GA4, I registered the custom dimension as a user level dimension. When I go into GA4's debugger, everything looks great. The custom dimension shows up with the proper value set.  However, I can't seem to run reports on this data.

I'm doing a super simple freeform exploration. For rows, I have my ab testing dimension. For columns, I just have active users (screen shot of all of this below). I would expect to see two rows that show the number of A users and number of B users. Instead I get one row that says "not set". Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks!

[image: ga4 settings]

Comment: did you map the correct parameter in GA4 dimension?

Comment: Have you tried any other metrics? Does it show for something other than Active Users?

Comment: @TusharGupta Yes. Like I said, I used the debug view to verify that the dimension is flowing into GA4.

Comment: @A_Patterson Yeah, I've tried other metrics too. Same result

Comment: debug view doesn't show dimensions, it just shows event parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not tell when you set the `custom dimension` in GA4. Where you set it?

Maybe you set it as event parameter but from your GA4 setting. You need to specify it is a `User Property` in Google Tag Manager

Two potential place you set the custom dimension.

So I add screenshots in both place

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot helped me find the problem! In Tag Manager, I was setting the custom dimension in the "Event Parameters" instead of the "User Properties". I fixed that and now it's working. Thanks